# Diagonal Relation as a poset I - establishing the result by vacous truth

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, order-theory, fake-proofs

I have a problem with the logic behind the fact that, given a nonempty set X, the diagonal relation $D_X := \{ (x,x) : x \in X \}$ is a partial order on $X$.

More specifically, my problem is with the fact that it looks to me that the result could be easily estabilished in the following way:

**Tentative "Proof":**
*Reflexivity:* The relation $D_X$ is reflexive by definition.
*Transitivity:* The relation is vacuously transitive, because there are no ordered pairs of the form $(x, \cdot)$, where the dot represents any element different from $x$.
*Antisymmetry:* The relation is vacuously antisymmetric for the same reasons that apply to transitivity.

In other words, as I pointed out in other previous questions, I have problems with the "range of application" of vacuously true statements, i.e. I don't really know when I should actually stop to apply this line of reasoning.

[For example, for a while I thought I could actually prove this is a linear order, out of this applying the vacuous truth anywhere. However, I realized that from $$\forall x, y \in X ((x,y) \in D_X \vee (y,x) \in D_X )$$ we get $(x,y) \notin D_X \Longrightarrow (y,x) \in D_X$, where the vacuous truth of the antecedent does not apply.]

Notice that I have an *alternative proof* (one I have no doubts about), definitely less concise, that avoids any reference to vacously true properties.

Thus, getting to the questions, does what I wrote (including the linear order excursus) make sense?
Is my *tentative proof* sound?

Any feedback is more than welcome. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: In the definition of transitivity, $(x,y) \in R\land (y,z)\in R \implies (x,z)\in R$, it isn't demanded that $x\neq y$ or $y\neq z$. Thus the transitivity is not _vacuously_ true, only trivially so, since $D_X$ is the neutral element for composition of relations.

Comment: Yes, I think Daniel's right: You need to distinguish between when a property holds *[vacuously](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)* vs. when it holds [*trivially.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triviality_%28mathematics%29)

Comment: So, here we have in antisymmetry and transitivity both properties holds *trivially*, while in this previous question of mine (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704058/problems-with-the-definition-of-transitive-relation) it's *vacuous*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "vacuously" means that there are no counterexamples. That is when we have an implication "If ... then !!!", but the "..." part **never** happens. But this is not the case, it's just happened that there are no *interesting* cases to verify.

This is because the definition of a transitive relation is not "For every $x,y,z$ *distinct* we have ..." but rather "For every $x,y,z$ ...". The case $x=y=z$ is trivial, and so non-interesting. But it means that the statement does not hold vacuously as you said.

If $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ are both in $D_X$ then by definition $x=y$ and $y=z$, therefore by transitivity of the equality relation $x=z$ and so $(x,z)\in D_X$ as well.

So there is something to verify here. It's just that this something is very trivial to check.

Comment: Going a bit further, is this definition ok (from the *triviality* link kindly provided by amWhy): "A trivial proof refers to a statement involving a material implication where $Q$, in $P \rightarrow Q$, is always true.Here, the proof follows simply from noting that $Q$ is always true, as the implication is then true regardless of the truth value of the antecedent, $P$.
A related concept is a vacuous proof, where the antecedent, $P$, in the material implication $P \rightarrow Q$ is always false. Here, the implication is always true regardless of the truth value of the consequent, $Q$.